# React Native SectionList not reliably rendering one of its sections

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, expo, use-effect, react-native-sectionlist

I have a custom `SectionList` component, called `EventSectionList`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SectionList } from 'react-native';
import { View, Text, Fab } from '../../../common/Layout';
import EventCard from '../EventCard';
import styles from './styles';

const EventSectionList = ({
  sections,
  refreshing,
  onRefresh,
  onEndReached,
  onFabPress,
  inExtraData,
}) => {
  const renderSectionHeader = ({ section: { title } }) => (
    <Text style={styles.sectionHeader}>{title}</Text>
  );

  const renderSectionFooter = () => <View style={styles.sectionSeparator} />;

  const renderSeparator = () => <View style={styles.itemSeparator} />;

  const renderFooter = () => <View style={styles.footer} />;

  const renderEvent = event => {
    const { item } = event;
    return <EventCard event={item} />;
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SectionList
        sections={sections}
        refreshing={refreshing}
        onRefresh={onRefresh}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0}
        onEndReached={onEndReached}
        renderItem={renderEvent}
        renderSectionHeader={renderSectionHeader}
        renderSectionFooter={renderSectionFooter}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={renderSeparator}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        extraData={inExtraData}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
      />
      <Fab icon="add" style={styles.fabAdd} onPress={onFabPress} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default EventSectionList;
```

An `EventSectionList` is being rendered here on the `EventsScreen`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment } from 'react';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import { Text } from '../../../common/Layout';
import { connect } from './../../../common/Helpers';
import EventSectionList from './../../Events/EventSectionList';
import styles from './styles';

const EventsScreen = ({ services }) => {
  const { eventsService } = services;
  const [hostedEvents, setHostedEvents] = useState([]);
  const [registeredEvents, setRegisteredEvents] = useState([]);
  const [eventSections, setEventSections] = useState(null);
  const [refreshing, setRefreshing] = useState(false);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(eventSections)) {
      setRefreshing(false);
    }
  }, [eventSections]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isEmpty(hostedEvents) || !isEmpty(registeredEvents)) {
      setEventSections([
        {
          title: 'Upcoming Hosted Events',
          data: hostedEvents,
        },
        {
          title: 'Upcoming Registered Events',
          data: registeredEvents,
        },
      ]);
    }
  }, [hostedEvents, registeredEvents]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const hostedEventsPromise = async () => {
      const { data } = await eventsService.getEvents({
        page,
        hosted: true,
        upcoming: true,
        page_size: 100,
      });
      if (page === 1) {
        setHostedEvents(data);
      } else {
        setHostedEvents([...hostedEvents, ...data]);
      }
    };

    const registeredEventsPromise = async () => {
      const { data } = await eventsService.getEvents({
        page,
        hosted: false,
        upcoming: true,
        page_size: 100,
      });
      if (page === 1) {
        setRegisteredEvents(data);
      } else {
        setRegisteredEvents([...registeredEvents, ...data]);
      }
    };

    registeredEventsPromise();
    hostedEventsPromise();
  }, [page]);

  const eventsRefresh = async () => {
    if (!refreshing) {
      setPage(1);
    }
  };

  const eventsRefreshEnd = async () => {
    if (!refreshing) {
      setPage(page + 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {eventSections ? (
        <EventSectionList
          sections={eventSections}
          inExtraData={registeredEvents}
          refreshing={refreshing}
          onRefresh={eventsRefresh}
          onEndReached={eventsRefreshEnd}
          onFabPress={() => {}}
        />
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.message}>You have no upcoming events.</Text>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default connect()(EventsScreen);
```

Unfortunately, sometimes - the **Registered Events section** doesn't render, until the pull - down refresh occurs, and even then - it doesn't always render. I can see this section sort of trying to render - the EventCards flicker where they should be rendered, but they don't "stick".

For reference, here is the `EventCard` component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { isEmpty } from 'lodash';
import moment from 'moment';
import { connect } from '../../../common/Helpers';
import { View, Text, Touchable } from '../../../common/Layout';
import { Image } from '../../../common/Image';
import styles from './styles';

const EventCard = ({ event }) => {
  const dateFormat = 'MMM D';
  const timeFormat = 'h:mm A';
  const [startDate] = useState(
    moment(event.start_date)
      .format(dateFormat)
      .toUpperCase()
  );
  const [startTime] = useState(moment(event.start_date).format(timeFormat));
  const [startDateTime] = useState(`${startDate} AT ${startTime}`);
  const [name] = useState(event.name);
  const [address] = useState(
    event.start_location && event.start_location.address
  );
  const [uri] = useState(event.cover_image);

  return (
    <Touchable>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {!isEmpty(uri) ? (
          <Image source={{ uri }} style={styles.detailsImage} />
        ) : (
          <Image name="eventPlaceholder" style={styles.detailsImage} />
        )}
        <View style={styles.detailsContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.detailsDate}>{startDateTime}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.detailsName}>{name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.detailsAddress}>{address}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </Touchable>
  );
};

export default connect()(EventCard);
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a key based on an event id instead of the using the index to generate the key?

Comment: @nipuna777 The ```EventSectionList``` is used for different kinds of event sections... how would I extract the event id from the sections?

Comment: You can try removing `keyExtractor` or using `Math.random()` for now. Just to check if the key not changing is the issue here.